# How to get all items in telerik RadDataBoundListBox

Tags: windows-phone-8, telerik

I am using `Telerik RadDataBoundListBox` for **windows phone 8** application. I have some error. How to get all items in `RadDataBoundListBox`? I used `RealizedItems` property but not getting the items. what property using for all items get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to get it from [ItemsSource](http://www.telerik.com/help/windows-phone/telerik.windows.controls.primitives-telerik.windows.controls.radvirtualizingdatacontrol-itemssource.html) property? For example :

```
<telerikPrimitives:RadDataBoundListBox x:Name="radDataBoundListBox" 
                    Height="200" Width="180"/>
.......
var items = radDataBoundListBox.ItemsSource;
```

**UPDATE :**

If you need to create a separate collection based on existing collection, you can try this way :

```
var items = radDataBoundListBox.ItemSource.cast<Model.Class1>;
var newItems = new List<Model.Class1>(items);
```

adding or removing items from `newitems` won't affect `items` or the opposite.

Comment: thank har07. I used 
var items = radDataBoundListBox.ItemSource.cast<Model.Class1>;

Comment: @PaingHeinThu so `radDataBoundListBox.ItemSource.cast<Model.Class1>;` works for you? I will edit my answer to that if you confirm it works. So that future visitors can spot the solution easily.

Comment: this method is ok for one RadDataBoundListBox. but I have three RadDataBoundListBox, AListBox,BListBox and CListBox. this three radDataBoundListBox itemsource  are using same Class List. so I filled BListBox.itemsource at the same time AListBox.itemsource change like BListBox.itemsource. so AListBox.itemsource are lose.

Comment: that sounds like different problem from what you described in the question. Check my update, is that what you're looking for? If it isn't, I suggest to describe more clearly about the new problem, open a new question for that is also ok.

Comment: I not using this method. I try another method. so i forgot mark answer. thank

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ItemsSource` property.

Read [RadDataBoundListBox Getting Started](http://www.telerik.com/help/windows-phone/raddataboundlistbox-getting-started.html) from official Telerik Windows Phone Help.